# Unable to install Misaka

Tags: python-3.x, django, misaka

I tried installing wheels and again ran pip install misaka but I'm ending up with the same error.
[Misaka installation error!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDV4M.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly says it.

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.
```

Install it and try again.